# Declaring Main as Static Throws Errors

Tags: c#, class, program-entry-point, static-methods

On my last compile, I received the following build errors:

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property ..."

and then a list of all of the items contained inside of my `Main()`.

Previously, it read `static Main() {`, but I could not get the errors to go away until I changed this to `public Main() {`.

I don't recall the last thing I did before this started occurring (this was late last night), but I do believe I was messing with the `static void recalcTotals()` trying to reference field items on the main form - to which I still have not figured it out, but that is a seperate issue.

Mind you, this is my first C# program. Below is basically my code:

```
namespace Play_XXX
{
    public partial class Main : Form 
    {
        // Enable moveability
        private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
        private const int HTCLIENT = 0x1;
        private const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;

        // Handling the window messages
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message message) {
            base.WndProc(ref message);

            if (message.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST && (int)message.Result == HTCLIENT)
                message.Result = (IntPtr)HTCAPTION;
        }

        public Main() {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Handle all auto-formatting textboxes
            txt1.Leave += new EventHandler(validateInput);
            txt2.Leave += new EventHandler(validateInput);
            txt3.Leave += new EventHandler(validateInput);
            txt4.Leave += new EventHandler(validateInput);
            txt5.Leave += new EventHandler(validateInput);
            txt6.Leave += new EventHandler(validateInput);
            txt7.Leave += new EventHandler(validateInput);
            txt8.Leave += new EventHandler(validateInput);
            txt9.Leave += new EventHandler(validateInput);
            txt10.Leave += new EventHandler(validateInput);
            txt11.Leave += new EventHandler(validateInput);
        }

        private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //TODO: Reference function to clear all input forms
        }

        static decimal? trueAmount(string testValue) {
            decimal preOut;

            //TODO: RegEx to remove all except digits?
            if (testValue != null && testValue != "")
                testValue = testValue.Replace(",", "").Replace("$", "");
            else
                testValue = "0";

            //Return value
            if (decimal.TryParse(testValue, out preOut))
                return preOut;
            else
                return null;
        }

        void validateInput(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            TextBox subjBox = (sender as TextBox);

            decimal? trueVal = trueAmount(subjBox.Text);

            //Check if this is a number
            if (trueVal.HasValue) {
                subjBox.Text = trueVal.Value.ToString("C");
                subjBox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(86, 86, 86);
                subjBox.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(208, 210, 211);
                recalcTotals();
            }
            else {
                subjBox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 200, 200);
                subjBox.ForeColor = Color.Maroon;
            }
        }

        static void recalcTotals() {
            //TODO: How the fxck do your reference form controls
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: And the error occurs on which line? Looks like the error is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: First thing to understand: compile-time errors and exceptions (which are thrown at *execution-time*) are very, very different. Next, you need to rename your class from `Main` to something else, given that you need a static *method* called `Main` as the entry point. I'd also *strongly* advise you to experiment with simple console apps to get the hang of core parts of the C# language before you start writing GUIs.

Comment: Do you need a void for the return type on main? static void main? Also validateInput looks like it might be missing the static deceleration on it.

Comment: @tnw The error occurs on every line inside of `Main()`. I am trying to figure out why this started occurring all of the sudden when the program was created with `Main()` as a `static`.

Comment: Please don't use `Main` to mean anything other than the entrypoint to an executable. You're just asking for trouble if you do.

Comment: I used your code exactly as is and it compiles and runs.  What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You know that `Main` is a form and cannot be declared `static`, right? What is the effect you desire to achieve here? Why are you trying to define a static form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your class everything other than `Main` (e.g. `MainForm`).

Comment: @jon-skeet I renamed the `Main()` class to `Default()` and it went ahead and renamed everything (the other instances of `Main()`) for me. I am still receiving the same errors. :(

Comment: First: A class name has no parentheses. Second: Applying the 'Rename' refactoring when you have a name clash messes all up. You must do it by hand in such a situation.

Comment: Thanks. I went found each occurrence an manually changed them. It was still giving the errors, so I created a new project to see how it looked by default, and the `Main()` that was generated was in fact a `public` by default. I will leave it that way for now but my understanding is that the `Main()` inside of the main class _should_ not be public.

Comment: @Rawrcasm: The `Main` method which is a static entrypoint into an executable can be public or private as you prefer. I generally prefer private.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a *constructor* looks different than a *method*.

A method has a name that is different from the class name, and it has a return type such as `void` or `int`. These are methods:

```
class C
{
  public void M1()
  {
  }
  public static void M2()
  {
  }
  public int M3()
  {
    return 10;
  }
  public static int M4()
  {
    return -10;
  }
}
```

Constructors must have the same name as the class and must not have a return type. These are constructors:

```
class C
{
  public C()
  {
  }
  static C()
  {
  }
}
```

Constructors are typically used to set up "state" before the class is used.

An *entry point* is a special method of which there can be only one in a program. The entry point must be a method, it must be `static` and it must be named `Main`. It follows that the entry point cannot be a direct member of a class that is also called `Main`.

I don't think it is usual to have the entry point inside the class that derives from `Form`, in a Windows Form application, but it should certainly be possible when the naming respects the above.

Furthermore, a non-static constructor or method can access all members of the class directly. When another non-static member is referred like that, the same instance of the class as the method/constructor belongs to (called `this`) is implicitly used to access the other member.

In contrast, a `static` constructor or method can only access a non-static member by explicitly having an instance, as in `myInstance.TheNonStaticMember();`. Typically, the entry point, which is a `static` method as I said, will create an instance with `new TheClassName(...)`.